# Executing multiple HTTP requests sequentially using async.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, async.js

How can I execute multiple HTTP requests sequentially using async.js . I checked the async.js documentation but couldn't figure out, how to do that. I want to achieve the same thing as below code using async.js callback style.

```
var http = require('http');
var Q = require('q');
var URL="http://localhost:3000";

var getPromise=function(url) {  
  var deferred  = Q.defer();
  var req = http.get(url, function(response) {
    if(response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 299){
            deferred.reject(new Error('ErrorCode '+response.statusCode))
        }   
      var result="";
        response.on('data',function(chunk){result +=chunk;} )
        response.on('end',function(){deferred.resolve(result);} ) 
  });

  req.on('error',function(err){
      console.error('Error with the request:', err.message); 
      deferred.reject(err); 
  });

  req.end();  
  return deferred.promise;
} 


getPromise('http://localhost:3000/olympic/2016/ranking/4')
      .then(function(data){
         console.log("Response 1 "+data)
         return getPromise(URL+'/iso/country/'+JSON.parse(data).Country);
      })
      .then(function(data){
         console.log("Response 2 "+data)
         return getPromise(URL+'/olympic/2016/medal/'+JSON.parse(data).iso);
      })
      .then(function(data){
        console.log("Response 3 "+data)
      })
      .catch(function(err){
         console.log(err)
      });
```

Comment: sequentially and async.js seem to be diametrically opposed to each other.

Comment: Contrary to the answers so far, it seems that you want to use the responses from the previous call in the current call. Consider using `async.seq` https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#seq

Comment: I've not used promises so not 100% sure how they work, but does each `.then` use values returned by the previous promise, or are they all separate calls?

Comment: @ScottMarcus shouldn't we sometime need result of previous HTTP request to finish and pass the response to make another HTTP call. I don't think async and sequential execution are completely opposite things.

Comment: What you are describing is somewhat of a synchronous process, which is the opposite of asynchronous. Yes, sometimes we do want that, but that is how JavaScript operates by default. Standard AJAX calls and JavaScript promises are for doing just what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the code a bit and trying to understand it more, I believe that [`async.waterfall`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall) is the function you'll need. What this will do is run each function in order, passing its results to the next function in the sequence. Here's an example:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback)
    {
        // Function 1: do request here...
        callback(null, val); // replace null with a value if you want the waterfall to error and go straight to the end
    },
    function(val, callback) {
        // Function 2: do your second request here
        callback(null, val1, val2, val3); // you can pass any number of variables you like, just make sure the next function in the sequence expects them
    },
    function(val1, val2, val3, callback)
    {
        // Function 3: do your third request here
        callback(null, result);
    } // this can go on for as long as you like
], function(err, result)
{
    // this will be called immediately if the first parameter in any of the callbacks is not null, or when all the functions have run
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I needed async.waterfall it takes an array of functions and execute them one by one. Also we can pass result from previous function execution to the next one

```
var async =  require('async');

async.waterfall([

  function task1(done) {
    console.log('start!');
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("T1 Complete"); 
        // <- set value to passed to step 2
        done(null, 'Value from step 1'); 
     },5000);

  },
  function task2(task1Result, done) {
    console.log(task1Result);
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("T2 Complete");
        // <- set value to passed to step 3
        done(null, 'Value from step 2');
      },1000);

  },
  function task3 (task2Result, done) {
    console.log(task2Result);
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("T3 Complete"); 
        // <- no value set for the next step.
        done(null); 
    },100);

  }
],
function (err) {
  if (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  } else {
    console.log('No error happened in any steps, operation done!');
  }
});
```